# Sails.js: How can I keep running code after serving res.view()?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, sails.js

According to sails [documentation](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/response-res/res-view), res.view() is terminal. Meaning it should be the last line of code for a given request.

However, some times I want to run code on the background without forcing the user to wait for it. Such as updating a log, or a background update related to this request.

What is the right way to implement such a thing?

Answer (score 3):

> it is **generally** the last line of code your app should run for a given request

It's not mandatory.

Just write the needed code after the `res.view()` call. It will run in background. 
Also, make sure you you **didn't** write `return` before the `res.view()`

Comment: I have tried that, but noticed that sails related code (such as updating the DB) is not working as expected after the res.view (I don't have an example at the moment). I assumed that by "terminal" they mean that they shut down some parts of the code.

Comment: 1) There's no such thing as 'code shut down'. 2) Actually, even if you write DB update code **above** the `res.view();`, It will be executed 'in background' due to async nature of such methods. 3) Anyway, need an example to see what's not working as expected.